Sci-fi action-horror film involving an age-reversal drug and a wartime ship rising up through the ice
Trying hard to find an odd movie I watched quite a while ago, most likely released from late-90s to early-2000s.  The cinematography, stunts, and effects were pretty good.  Acting was passable for this type of feature.
The story was about a man who had developed a serum to temporarily make his body 20+ years younger, and had three combat-skilled young women working with him to search for ways to make the reverse-aging permanent.  The young women may have been his daughters.  A submersible ship appeared in the Arctic, rising out of the ice, which turned out to be some kind of weird research facility.  The ship was controlled by zombie soldiers wearing long trench coats with the German-style helmets, and an officer dressed in all-black Nazi-style attire. I cannot pinpoint seeing swastikas, but think they were evident. In one scene, there was a non-German scientist engaged in a sexual encounter with a mostly-naked woman, which did not end well for either participant.  The story took place in current time, making the vessel residents essentially ageless.  There was some type of video feed from the ship, and the man sends one of his daughters to check out the source.  After she disappears, the remaining two daughters take it upon themselves to follow up where the first daughter failed.  In the end, the vessel's origin or whereabouts remained unknown.
Sorry for the sketchy details.  I do not recall any of the actors being notable stars.  Most likely this was a direct-to-video release, probably not appearing on broadcast TV unless rated MA or cut because of the bloodshed and one sex scene.  I searched multiple times through my archives, plus used several AI-based movie search websites and viewed dozens of story/character-related movies, but could not re-discover this particular one.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

You reference the Nazi-like soldiers - but what was the nationality/background of the scientist or the women? Were they caucasian (European or American?), or were they asian? Was this an english-language film? For some of us, this helps determine if we ever saw such a movie.

@LogicDictates: I last watched it a couple of years ago, maybe 2022 or so.  Before that, it was probably before 2020.  I was sure I still had it in my archives, but despite a detailed search, I could not find it again.

@ArlettaS: Best as I can remember, the actors were all caucasian, and the dialog was in non-dubbed English.  It is possible that  some of the participants were European, but most seemed to be American.

Is this Sky Sharks (2020)...?

Deep in the ice of the antarctic, a team of geologists uncover an old Nazi laboratory still intact where dark experiments had occurred. In order to conquer the world, the Nazis created modified sharks who were able to fly.

This is a German film, but the dialogue is mostly in English and the plot unfolds in a variety of locations around the world. The cast also includes a few American actors, such as Tony Todd, Cary-Hiroyuki Tagawa and Robert LaSardo, in small roles.
If this is the right film, then the man you initially referred to in your description would be Dr. Klaus Richter. Before defecting to the US in 1945, he was a Nazi scientist working on K7B, a regenerative serum designed to increase the resilience and lifespan of living German soldiers and revive dead German soldiers as zombies. The Nazis were also working on flying sharks to be used as weapons of war. In the present day, Dr. Richter heads his own company, Richter Technology, and is 115 years old, but regularly injects himself with K7B, giving him the physical conditioning of a 75-year-old. He has two adult daughters, Diabla and Angelique, who both work for him.



In an early scene, Diabla is sent to the Arctic to investigate an old German warship previously frozen in ice but now thawing out due to global warming. Two scientists (one male, one female) based at a nearby Richter Technology research station are already on the ship and are having sex when they're surprised and killed by zombie Nazi soldiers. Diabla boards the ship and discovers that there's a whole army of zombie Nazis there preparing for war. She fights a few of them and escapes the ship just before it submerges beneath the ice. Dr. Richter observes some of this through a live feed being sent to the Richter Technology building in Manhattan.



Diabla then returns to the US to have her injuries treated while the zombie Nazis use their flying sharks to launch attacks on major cities around the world. A video conference is held between Dr. Richter and representatives of the US, the UK, Germany, France and Japan to plan a counterattack and Diabla and Angelique board a military aircraft to execute it, in cooperation with soldiers and scientists from those nations.




I want to see this. Hopefully it's not one where it's so bad I turn it off within the first 10 minutes. But I've sat through most of the weird shark movies.

@Logic Dictates: Thank you very much for your response.  I had this title suggested before on another forum, but dismissed it because I thought the shark aspect was not part of the one I was seeking.  Thanks to the detail you provided, I did confirm that this was the right movie, and marked it as the correct answer.  Sincerely appreciated!
